# Informatica Connector

Tags: streaming, informatica, twitter-streaming-api

Is it possible to write a Streaming API Connector and publish in Informatica?
If possible can use it to trigger any WorkFlow in Informatica.
Please add Code Snippets if possible.

Comment: If you want to trigger PowerCenter workflows from other applications, you can call the Informatica web serice.

Answer (score 2):

On the INFA site, look for a document called the Informatica Connectory Toolkit Developer Guide.  That's where I would start for writing a new connector.

That being said, it looks like you are going to do something with Twitter?  I believe that they already have a connector for Twitter that you can license.

Hope this helps,

-DM

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Informatica cloud, there you will find tons of connectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using informatica developer client and not powercenter, you can use Informatica Connector Toolkit to create connectors. Its very easy to develop and publish to your repository. The developer connector tool kit was actually released to develop custom cloud connectors and later extended to on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

You can import any wsdl as source in Informatica

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are using Informatica PowerCenter (On premise).

So. Informatica have something called "command line utilities". Check this article for that: http://exploreinformatica.com/how-to-start-a-workflow-using-pmcmd/

pmcmd also works at Unix/Linux... Review the command line reference.

If you are talking about Informatica Cloud, check the connectors. I think you can't publish your API at Informatica cloud, but you can install the command line utilities at the agent and run a SH or BAT script to call on premise workflows.

Good luck!